# How to separate unique characters from several words in a "indic" text file?

Tags: unix, tr, chars

I've a plain text file.

```
> Input: इंजेक्शन इंटरनॅशनल इंटिग्रेटेड इंटिरिअर इंडस्ट्री
```

All words are separated by one or more spaces. I want to collect all unique chars from the text file. I'm looking for a unix command; the order of the result chars is not important.

```
> Expected result: इं जे क्श न ट र नॅ श ल इ्रे टे ड टि रिअ र ड स्ट्री
```

With the command Klaus has provided

```
cat <file>|sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g'|sort -u|tr -d '\n'
```

Result comes as:

> ं अ इ क ग ज ट ड न र ल श सिीॅे्

I don't want to separate horizontal or vertical conjuncts or dependent vowels from its base character.

I just want to separate complete characters in a word from each other.

Can we achieve this with UNIX commands?

> "base character"   +    "dependent vowel"  =  "complete character"

```
 -  क                   ा                        का 
 -  क                   ि                        कि
```

Klaus's command works for English text only. But, It doesn't work with indic languages such as Hindi.

> Input: hi1 hello-2  how!3     "are4  ?you5
>
> result: h i e l o w a r y u 1 2 3 4 5 - ! "

Note:- You have to install Indic support in your OS.
Also, download Mangal font from http://hindi-fonts.com/fonts/Mangal

Comment: This should be on SuperUser rather than StackOverflow really, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
cat <file>|sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g'|sort -u|tr -d '\n'
```

or simplified ( stolen from  fedorqui comment, thanks! Never seen `&` before in the replacement part. Good to learn something new! )

```
sed 's/./&\n/g' <file> | sort -u | tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: I like this approach. I would suggest some improvements: get rid of `cat | sed`, because `sed '...' file` does the same. Also, this alone would make, no need to catch a group: `sed 's/./&\n/g' file | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '`

Comment: Thanks! Never seen `&` in the replacement part before :-)

Comment: Klaus, fedorqui: Thanks. command works fine for english text. I have unicode text: "इंजेक्शन इंटरनॅशनल इंटिग्रेटेड इंटिरिअर इंडस्ट्री" I am expecting result as: इं जे क्श न ट र नॅ श ल इ्रे टे ड टि रिअ र ड स्ट्री

Comment: Sorry, my local desktop installation is not able to handle these chars you are provided. So I couldn't reproduce the results for you. Seems to be that the charset is not complete.